# Lazy WebClient download

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm downloading a ~3MB text file using `WebClient.DownloadString()`, but I only need the first twenty lines of that file. Is there a way to get them without downloading the whole file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get hold of the HttpWebResponse, call GetResponseStream, call Read on it until you fetched what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx

This doesn't necessarily reduce the load on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`WebClient.OpenStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/781fwaz8.aspx) as in the example in the link.
Just replace `sr.ReadToEnd()` with 20x `sr.ReadLine()`.